# Why can't R handle inequalities between negative numbers in quotes

Tags: r, numeric, quote, inequality

This is a weird problem, with an easy workaround, but I'm just so curious why R is behaving this way.

```
> "-1"<"-2"
[1] TRUE
> -1<"-2"
[1] TRUE
> "-1"< -2
[1] TRUE
> -1< -2
[1] FALSE
> as.numeric("-1")<"-2"
[1] TRUE
> "-1"<as.numeric("-2")
[1] TRUE
> as.numeric("-1")<as.numeric("-2")
[1] FALSE
```

What is happening? Please, for my own sanity...

Answer (score 3):

A "number in quotes" is not a number at all, it is a string of characters. Those characters happen to be displayed with the same drawing on your screen as the corresponding number, but they are fundamentally not the same object.

The behavior you are seeing is consistent with the following:

- A pair of numbers (`numeric` in R) is compared in the way that you should expect, numerically with the natural ordering. So, -1 < -2 is indeed `FALSE`.
- A pair of strings (`character` in R) are compared in lexicographic order, meaning roughly that it is compared alphabetically, character by character, from left to right. Since "-1" and "-2" start with the same character, we move to the second, and "2" comes after "1", so "-2" comes after "-1" and therefore "-1" < "-2" is `TRUE`.
- When comparing objects of mismatched types, you have two basic choices: either you give an error, or you convert one of the types to the other and then fall back on the two facts above. R takes the 2nd route, and chooses to convert `numeric` to `character`, which explains the result you got above (all your mismatched examples give `TRUE`).

Note that it makes more sense to convert `numeric` to `character`, rather than the other way around, because most `character` can't be automatically converted to `numeric` in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 0):

I've always thought this is because the default behavior is to treat the values in quotes as character, and the values without quotes as double. Without expressly declaring the data types, you get this:

```
> typeof(-1)
[1] "double"
> typeof("-1")
[1] "character"
> typeof(as.numeric("-1"))
[1] "double"
```

It's only when the negative numbers are put in quotes that it orders them alphabetically, because they are characters.